# Difference between @Self and @Host Angular 2+ Dependency Injection Decorators

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular2-services, angular-decorator

Kindly explain the difference between [`@Self`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Self-decorator.html) and [`@Host`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Host-decorator.html).

The angular API documentation gives some idea. But it's not clear to me.
The example provided for `Self` uses `ReflectiveInjector` to exemplify usage.

However, one would rarely, if ever, use `ReflectiveInjector` in actual app code (probably more in testing).. Can you give an example of where you would use `@Self` **instead** of `@Host` outside of such test scenarios??

Comment: How's the example I described? Does it clarify things for you?

Comment: thanks for making an effort to make it clearer... What would be most helpful is a plunkr  showing two examples that otherwise equivalent.. but different enough to concretely show what is different ..

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### tl;dr

It looks like when `@Self` is used, Angular will only look for a value that is bound on the component injector for the element that this Directive/Component exists on.

It looks like when `@Host` is used, Angular will look for a value that is bound on either the component injector for the element that this Directive/Component exists on, or on the injector of the parent component. Angular calls this parent component the "host".

### More explanation

Although the main descriptions aren't very helpful, it looks like the examples in the documentation for [@Self](https://angular.io/api/core/Self) and [@Host](https://angular.io/api/core/Host) do a decent job of clarifying how they are used and what the difference is (copied below).

When trying to understand this, it might help to remember that when Angular dependency injection tries to resolve a particular value for a constructor, it starts by looking in the injector for the current component, then it iterates upward through parent injectors. This is because Angular uses hierarchical injectors and allows for inheritance from ancestor injectors.

So when the `@Host` documentation says that it "specifies that an injector should retrieve a dependency from any injector until reaching the host element of the current component", that means that it stops this upward iteration early once it reaches the injector bound to the parent component.

### @Self example ([source](https://angular.io/api/core/Self#example))

```
class Dependency {}

@Injectable()
class NeedsDependency {
  constructor(@Self() public dependency: Dependency) {}
}

let inj = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([Dependency, NeedsDependency]);
const nd = inj.get(NeedsDependency);

expect(nd.dependency instanceof Dependency).toBe(true);

inj = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([Dependency]);
const child = inj.resolveAndCreateChild([NeedsDependency]);
expect(() => child.get(NeedsDependency)).toThrowError();
```

### @Host example ([source](https://angular.io/api/core/Host#example))

```
class OtherService {}
class HostService {}

@Directive({selector: 'child-directive'})
class ChildDirective {
  logs: string[] = [];

  constructor(@Optional() @Host() os: OtherService, @Optional() @Host() hs: HostService) {
    // os is null: true
    this.logs.push(`os is null: ${os === null}`);
    // hs is an instance of HostService: true
    this.logs.push(`hs is an instance of HostService: ${hs instanceof HostService}`);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-cmp',
  viewProviders: [HostService],
  template: '<child-directive></child-directive>',
})
class ParentCmp {
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  viewProviders: [OtherService],
  template: '<parent-cmp></parent-cmp>',
})
class App {
}
```

### Example of when using @Self is important

Let's say you have a directive that is used to modify the behavior of many types of components; maybe this directive provides some sort of configuration support.

This directive is bound to many components throughout your app and this directive binds some service in its `providers` list. Components that want to use this directive to dynamically configure themselves will inject the service it provides.

However, we want to make sure that a component only uses its own configuration, and doesn't accidentally inject the configuration service that was meant for some parent component. So we use the `@Self` decorator to tell Angular's dependency injection to only consider the configuration service provided on this component's element.

Comment: Just for clarification! I saw in some example they using @Self() and @Host() at once.
The default behavior of DI is equal == @Self() and @Host. What i meant is: when i only want to get the injector of the component itself i have to use @Self() and when i want to get the injector from the parent component i have to use @Host()

Comment: I found the explanation in [this angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#make-a-dependency-optional-and-limit-search-with-host) what the _host component_ is quiet nice:  
`The host component is typically the component requesting the dependency. However, when this component is projected into a parent component, that parent component becomes the host.`

Answer (score 17):

Angular resolves dependencies by searching for them within the hierarchy of element injectors starting on the injector for the current element, then moving onto that for the parent element if it's not found there, and so on. If the dependency is still not found, it moves onto the module injectors. If it isn't found there, an error is thrown. https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#host

@Self and @Host are modifiers that tell Angular on which injectors it should stop looking for dependencies.

#### @Self

@Self tells Angular that it should only look within the injector on the current element. An important point to note regarding this is that every element has just one injector that is shared by every directive that is attached to it. Thus, in this template snippet:

```
<div dir-1 dir-2></div>
```

Assuming that `dir-1` corresponds to Directive1, and `dir-2` corresponds to Directive2,
if Directive1 registers a provider, then Directive2 will be able to inject that service, and vice-versa.

If a dependency has the @Self modifier, this means that Angular will only look within the current element's injector for a provider. Unless the @Optional modifier is also present, an error will be thrown if it can't find it.

The use-case for @Self is if you want a service to be injected into a directive, or component, only if another directive on the same element provides it. (The directive can obviously supply the service itself, but that seems to make the use of @Self a bit redundant).

#### Proof

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-di-test-4-6jxjas?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html
Consider this template in `app.component.html`

```
<div my-directive-alpha>
    <h1 my-directive-beta my-directive-gamma>Lorem Ipsum..</h1>
</div>
```

Let `my-directive-alpha` correspond to MyDirectiveAlpha, `my-directive-beta` correspond to MyDirectiveBeta, and `my-directive-gamma` to MyDirectiveGamma.

When MyDirectiveGamma attempts to inject MehProvider:

```
  constructor(@Self() meh: MehProvider) {
    console.log("gamma directive constructor:", meh.name);
  }
```

Both MyDirectiveAlpha and MyDirectiveBeta configure MehProvider within their providers array.
If you delete my-directive-beta from the template, you'll get an error saying that Angular can't find MehProvider.
If you then remove the @Self decorator from MyDirectiveGamma, Angular will find MehProvider from within the MyDirectiveAlpha. Thus, the @Self modifier restricts Angular to looking at the injector on the current element.

#### @Host

@Host tells Angular that it should stop looking for providers beyond the injector for the current template. For the purposes of this article, I call this the *template injector*, but Angular's documentation does not use this term. This injector contains those providers from the *viewProviders* array of the component. A component may also have a *providers* array, which configures an injector that I will call the *component injector*.

So for this component:

```
<my-component></my-component>
```

With this template:

```
<div>
  <h2>my component</h2>
  <div my-dir-1>
    <div my-dir-2>lorem ipsum...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Assuming `my-dir-1` corresponds to MyDirective1, and `my-dir-2` corresponds to MyDirective2, if MyDirective2  attempts to inject a dependency annotated with the @Host modifier:

```
constructor(@Host() foo: FooProvider) {
...
}
```

Then Angular will search through all element injectors up through the tree of elements, but not go beyond the template injector of MyComponent. If the provider is not found, again assuming that the @Optional modifier is not present, then an error will be thrown.

An error will still be thrown even if the provider exists within the component injector because Angular will not search there. Thus we can conclude that the component injector is a level above the template injector.

The use case for @Host is to ensure that the containing component of a directive has control of how a particular service is injected.

#### Proof

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-di-host-modifier-proof?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-component%2Fmy-component.component.ts

Consider MyComponent:

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-component",
  providers: [{provide: FooProvider, useValue: {name: 'FooProvider from providers'}}],
  viewProviders: [{provide: FooProvider, useValue: {name: 'FooProvider from view-providers'}}],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>This is my component</h2>
      <div>
        <h3 my-directive>Lorem Ipsum...</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,

})
export class MyComponent {}
```

Let `my-directive` correspond to MyDirective.
Given that MyDirective attempts to inject FooProvider and uses the @Host modifier:

```
  constructor(@Host() foo: FooProvider) {
    console.log("my directive:", foo.name);
  }
```

The actual instance of FooProvider that is injected is that from within viewProviders array. If we comment out this array, we get an error that tells us Angular cannot find the provider, even though it still exists within the providers array. Thus @Host prevents Angular from looking beyond the template injector of a component for providers.

Comment: The use case for `@Self` here is great - that's the missing piece of the puzzle for me. These decorators also seem to be useful for directives more-so than components - and as far as I know that's how Angular uses them in Reactive Form implementation

Answer (score 3):

https://netbasal.com/exploring-the-various-decorators-in-angular-b208875b207c

Host:

> @Host —
>   The @Host decorator tells DI to look for a dependency in any injector until it reaches the host

Self:

> @Self —
>   The @Self decorator tells DI to look for a dependency only from itself, so it will not walk up the tree

here is an example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/UmpPTnzcRxgDc9Hn5I9G?p=preview

As you see MyDir directive use:
@Self to access its own Car
Its component' @Host Garage dependency
@Optional @Host Sun dependency that is not defined on Host but defined on App. Since it is not defined on Host - it will be null

Output will be:

```
 parent component. 
  { "type": "child garage", 
    "car": { "model": "child car" }, 
    "sun": null 
  }
```

Here is components and providers:

```
  class Garage {
    car;
    type;
    sun;

    constructor(type) {
      this.type=type;
    }
    setCar(car) {
      this.car = car;
    }
    setSun(sun) {
      this.sun = sun;
    }
  }

  class Car {
    model;
    constructor(model) {
      this.model=model;
    }
  }

  class Sun { }

  @Directive({
    selector: '[myDir]',
    providers:[
      {provide: Car, useValue: new Car('child car')}
      {provide: Garage, useValue: new Garage('child garage')}
    ]
  })
  export class MyDir {
    constructor(@Self() private car: Car, @Host() private garage: Garage,
      @Optional() @Host() private sun: Sun) {
       this.garage.setCar(this.car);
       this.garage.setSun(this.sun);
    }
  }

  @Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    template: `
       parent component. {{garage|json}}
    `,
    providers:[
      {provide: Car, useValue: new Car('parent car')},
      {provide: Garage, useValue: new Garage('parent garage')}
    ]
  })
  export class Parent {
    childDep;
    constructor(private car: Car, private garage: Garage) {
    }
  }

  @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
  <parent myDir></parent>
    `,
    providers:[
      {provide: Car, useValue: new Car('app car')},
      {provide: Garage, useValue: new Garage('app garage')},
      {provide: Sun, useValue: 'sun'}
    ]
  })
  export class App {
  }
```

Comment: No this does not suffice. Because replacing @Self with @Host in the example provided under the `Self` section (all else equal) results in exactly the same output as before see https://plnkr.co/edit/IvXGWEsINi2XjkaI631k?p=info

Comment: You may find a better explanation here: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/08/20/host-and-visibility-in-angular-2-dependency-injection.html.

It's also worth mentioning that when the `@Host` decorator is applied, only the values assigned to the parent injector via `viewProviders` will be used. The big thing about `@Host` seems to be that it enforces the constraint that only the _immediate_ host container's parameters may be used, otherwise an error will be thrown. I didn't get around to finishing it, but here's a quick playground: https://plnkr.co/edit/4eyMr0GLmsqEh8nZgXZq?p=preview

Comment: @MikeHill Can you please explain why does `my-app-component-3` in the playground  - doesn't show nothing ? if it traverse to top - it should show the main provider in the main module (`AppModule provider`). no ? https://plnkr.co/edit/xogIMliobSuPHITfKR0i?p=preview

Comment: It helps understanding if you take away the following provider from **`MyDir`**: 
**`{provide: Garage, useValue: new Garage('child garage')}`**. I think it will be clearer that it will use the host injector for **`Garage`**.

Answer (score 0):

@self can use directive/component self provider. but host is not

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[myDir]',
    providers:[
      {provide: Car, useValue: new Car('child car')}
    ]
  })
export class Parent {
 constructor(@Self() private car: Car){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Self()` and `@Host()` are very similar, we can see some differences when using **content projection** or **viewProviders**

Given a dummy service

```
export class DummyService {
  constructor(public name: string) {}
}
```

#### Content Projection

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [AComponent, BComponent],
  template: `
  <app-a>
    <app-b></app-b>
  </app-a>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-a',
  standalone: true,
  providers: [
    { provide: DummyService, useValue: new DummyService('ComponentA') },
  ],
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class AComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-b',
  standalone: true,
  template: `{{ dummyService.name }}` // ComponentA
})
export class BComponent {
  constructor(@Host() public dummyService: DummyService) {}
}
```

Using `@Self()` would produce the following error

```
Error: NG0201: No provider for DummyService found in NodeInjector
```

When providing the service in `ComponentB`, `@Host()` and `@Self()` produce the same result

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-b',
  standalone: true,
  providers: [
    { provide: DummyService, useValue: new DummyService('ComponentB') },
  ],
  template: `{{ dummyService.name }}` // ComponentB
})
export class BComponent {
  constructor(@Host() public dummyService: DummyService) {}
  // or
  constructor(@Self() public dummyService: DummyService) {}
}
```

#### View Providers

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [AComponent],
  template: `<app-a></app-a>`
})
export class AppComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-a',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [BComponent],
  viewProviders: [
    { provide: DummyService, useValue: new DummyService('ComponentA') }
  ],
  template: `<app-b></app-b>`
})
export class AComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-b',
  standalone: true,
  template: `{{ dummyService.name }}` // ComponentA
})
export class BComponent {
  constructor(@Host() public dummyService: DummyService) {}
}
```

Using `@Self()` or `providers` instead of `viewProviders` would produce the following error

```
Error: NG0201: No provider for DummyService found in NodeInjector
```

As above, when providing the service in `ComponentB`, `@Host()` and `@Self()` produce the same result

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-b',
  standalone: true,
  providers: [
    { provide: DummyService, useValue: new DummyService('ComponentB') },
  ],
  template: `{{ dummyService.name }}` // ComponentB
})
export class BComponent {
  constructor(@Host() public dummyService: DummyService) {}
  // or
  constructor(@Self() public dummyService: DummyService) {}
}
```

#### Extra Note

`@Host()` and `@Self()` parameters decorators could be replaced by injection flags :

```
dummyService = inject(DummyService, {host: true}); 
dummyService = inject(DummyService, {self: true});
```

Answer (score -1):

Decorator `@Host()` used only in context the components and the directives. It does a similar work as a decorator `@Self()` does for the services.