# How exactly does Host resolution modifier affect the process of injection?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

Angular's [Hierarchical Dependency Injection](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection) guide encourages us to look at the DI from the perspective of a combined logical tree.

Regarding `@Host()` modifier, the guide states that it limits the upper bound of the search to the `<#VIEW>` of that logical structure and provides us with an example of `@Host()` modifier being used along with `@SkipSelf` and `@Host`.

```js
<app-root @NgModule(AppModule)
        @Inject(FlowerService) flower=>"">
  <#VIEW> <!-- end search here with null-->
    <app-child @Provide(FlowerService="")> <!-- start search here -->
      <#VIEW @Inject(FlowerService, @SkipSelf, @Host, @Optional)=>null>
      </#VIEW>
      </app-parent>
  </#VIEW>
</app-root>
```

Then, the guide says that using `viewProviders` means the dependency is going to be available in `<#VIEW>` and demonstrates how the dependency is successfully resolved when provided in the `AppComponent` via `viewProviders` array.

```js
<app-root @NgModule(AppModule)
        @Inject(AnimalService=>"")>
  <#VIEW @Provide(AnimalService="")
         @Inject(AnimalService, @SkipSelf, @Host, @Optional)=>"">
    <!-- ^^@SkipSelf() starts here,  @Host() stops here^^ -->
    <app-child>
      <#VIEW @Provide(AnimalService="")
             @Inject(AnimalService, @SkipSelf, @Host, @Optional)=>"">
               <!-- Add @SkipSelf ^^-->
      </#VIEW>
      </app-child>
  </#VIEW>
</app-root>
```

So according to this analogy, when I provide a dependency via `providers` option and make use of `@Host` modifier in the `constructor` of my component, like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `<p>Emoji from AnimalService: {{animal.emoji}}</p>`,
  providers: [{ provide: AnimalService, useValue: { emoji: '' } }]
})

export class ChildComponent {
  constructor(@Host() @Optional() public animal: AnimalService) {}
}
```

I expect to get the following logical tree:

```js
<app-root>
  <#VIEW>
    <app-child @Provide(AnimalService="")>
      <#VIEW @Inject(AnimalService, @Host, @Optional)=>null> <!-- start and end search here with null-->
      </#VIEW>
      </app-parent>
  </#VIEW>
</app-root>
```

I can't figure out how it reaches the `<app-child>`, because `@Host()` should limit the upper bound of the search to the `<#VIEW>` and stop the injector from looking any further. What am I missing?

Here is the [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pprfwp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you understand each of these modifiers correctly, but in the OP and StackBlitz demo you've shared you're not utilizing `@SkipSelf` in the child, you're using `@Optional`. If you replace `@Optional` with `@SkipSelf` you'll get the error you expect. Updated (forked) demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pprfwp-rqexep).

Now, also of note is that in your example/demo you're using the `providers` key in your component decorator. This is quite different than `viewProviders`, and it will have consequences for how your demo aligns with Angular's documentation.

```
@Component({
  /**
   * What goes in this array is going to be provided to the Element
   * injector in the view for this component. What does that mean?
   * When an element requires something from the DI system, it will
   * be able to find it.
   */
  viewProviders: []
})
```

It may be counterintuitive then that you could have a child of this component with `@SkipSelf` and `@Host` and have it still find something specified here, but let's try to understand why.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<app-child></app-child>`,
  viewProviders: [{ provide: AnimalService, useValue: { emoji: '' } }]
})
export class AppComponent  {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `<p>Emoji from AnimalService: {{animal.emoji}}</p>`
})
export class ChildComponent {
  /** this component still works, the injector knows where to look */
  constructor(@Host() @SkipSelf() public animal: AnimalService) {}
}
```

An explanation for the weirdness above can be found [here](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#host-and-viewproviders).

If you were to replace `@Host` with `@Self` I think you'd see behavior that made sense - namely, an error. For helpful clarification on this distinction, [this question/answer is great](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45131444).

Edit: I realize I was probably too flippant about why you would expect to see an error. You will see an error because Angular's DI cannot find the provider specified in the component. If you want to silence that error, you may use `@Optional` along with the other options, that's outlined [here in Angular's docs](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#skipself-with-optional).

Edit 2: It occurs to me that perhaps what is confusing here is the distinction between `viewProviders` and `providers` in the Component API. Your XML diagrams are showing a distinction between them, where `VIEW` is inside of some `app-child`. And in reality is it possible that the confusion is around which injector is being configured. I've updated my answer with clarification on this distinction.

Comment: I intentionally omitted ```@SkipSelf``` in my demo because it seems to me like ```@Host``` modifier has no sense until injector of the current component has been skipped with ```@SkipSelf```. And if so, only then that logical tree rules come into play.

Otherwise, following my logic, it should not go further up ```<#VIEW>``` belonging to ```<app-child>``` but thanks to ```@Optional``` resolve the dependency as ```null```.

Comment: Ah, then there is your answer. Your assumption that `@Host` doesn't do anything until you use some other modifier is incorrect. `@Host` does what Angular's docs say it does: it limits the scope of the injector's search to the component.